# jQuery slideToggle "flicker" on page load

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I know there are many questions about jQuery slideToggle "flickering" but I haven't seen any that specifically address this flicker upon page load.

Click **[here](http://www.pottersignal.com/datasheets_firesprinkler.aspx)** for the working example.

If you click Refresh or click on another datasheet page (under the Datasheets & Product Info section), when the page loads, the hidden div "flashes" the expanded content and then quickly collapses. I notice this in Firefox, not so much in IE or Chrome. What can I do to prevent this? Does this depend on the speed with which the page loads?

Also, please excuse the nightmarish tabulated code. I inherited this from a previous developer. We are planning to go back and correct this in a later phase, but I'm wondering if there is a quick fix for this issue now.

Thanks!

Comment: I have handled something similar the way lonut says and it usually works.  Just FYI, I am on a medium-slow network and it does not flicker in Firefox 3.6, or Opera 10.6.  It is doing it in IE6 (but who cares).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `display:none` for elements like `#mover2` ?
(of course, that also mean no graceful degradation)

EDIT (a reply to another question)
To avoid using #id, #id1, #id2 in your css, you can simply add an extra class to those divs, like `hideThis`.

Then, in CSS you can just add:
    .hideThis {display:none; }

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the latency of the javascript in Firefox on loading I believe.

I addressed this by, as Ionut Staicu suggests, hiding them in the .CSS which is likely faster than the hide method.

I would also try `$('[id=^mover]').hide();` instead of all the individual ones like `$('#mover1').hide();`

Comment: the flick will be there because the `.hide()` thing is called AFTER dom is ready. So you have to hide it via css :)

Comment: You guys are so freaking helpful! Can I pick your brain one more time? Is there a handy short-hand way to type #mover1, #mover2, #mover3...{display:none;} rather than type each selector out individually? On one page I have up to 20 of these things. 

Thanks so much!

Comment: the $('[id=^mover]').hide(); is the selecter you ask for. It says every "id" attribute that starts with "mover". You could also put them as $("mover1, mover2, mover3").hide(); instead of separate ones (this is the jQuery selector) not sure for the CSS other than what you have.

Comment: One more thing I've noticed: This works in both IE and Firefox, but not Chrome. Do I have to leave the jQuery .hide() function in for Chrome?

Comment: One other suggestion. You could add a "class='moverclass'" to all your mover div's and then use the .moverclass {display:none;} selector.